# Yii2 Captcha Image not showing

Tags: yii2, captcha

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                                              ]); ?>
```

Passed requirement in yii2 requirement like GD and imagick liberies but captcha image is not showing.

Comment: Did you do the required configuration in the controller as told in this guide https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-captcha/ ?

Comment: public function actions() {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

Yes i do and also find out the solution but not working.

Comment: check your rules

Comment: Is the variable captcha is set as captcha in the model rules?

Comment: Yes i have set captcha in my model.

Comment: add <?php ob_clean() ?> before your captcha code in view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
} else {
        ob_clean();  //Add this line, can solve this problem. Or add in other suitable places
        $this->setHttpHeaders();
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
        return $this->renderImage($this->getVerifyCode());
    }
```

This will help,
please change in \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\captcha\CaptchaAction.php and will show image.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set 'captcha' rules in your model .

```
['captcha', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'site/captcha']
```

first captcha is your property and next one is the type of rules

be sure to set controller

```
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: add <?php ob_clean() ?> before your captcha code in view and if your issue not fix  please get a screenshot  and from the inspect elemnt  of your captcha line in html/view @user7961310

Comment: Not working.
in inspect element given "Failed to load the given url".

Comment: url  is /web/infex/captacha ?

Comment: /my_yii2_project/site/captcha?v=5a45d9c406a7c

Comment: it's correct ,  you have to check your phpinfo to sure GD or imagick is enabled . if it's makbe you don't permission on that place for your yii app .

Comment: Passed in yii2 requirement like GD and imagick liberies but captcha image is not showing also permission is give 0777 of folder.

Comment: did you try crate new porject on other folder and see defualt contact form of yii ?

Answer (score 0):

```
} else {
    ob_clean();  //Add this line, can solve this problem. Or add in other suitable places
    $this->setHttpHeaders();
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    return $this->renderImage($this->getVerifyCode());
}
```

Comment: please provide some context and reformat code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . here where you should take information about it

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not proper to edit the classes in the vendor folder, Just extend the desired class and make the modification from my case

```
<?php
namespace app\components;
use lubosdz\captchaExtended\CaptchaExtendedAction;
use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\Response;

class captchaCustom extends CaptchaExtendedAction
{
    /**
     * @throws InvalidConfigException
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if(isset($_GET[self::REFRESH_GET_VAR])){
            $result = $this->getVerifyResult(true); // we must hash the result, not the code
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return [
                'hash1' => $this->generateValidationHash($result),
                'hash2' => $this->generateValidationHash(mb_convert_case($result, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'utf-8')),
                'url' => Url::to([$this->id, $this->paramRefreshUrl => uniqid()]),
            ];
        }else{
            ob_clean();  //Add this line, can solve this problem. Or add in other suitable places
            $this->setHttpHeaders();
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
            return $this->renderImage($this->getVerifyCode());
        }
    }
}
```